# Issue on Web Service - Big size request with byte[]

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, iis-7, arrays, requestfiltering

I'm facing a problem with web services in a IIS + Sharepoint farm...

I have a Web service that receives a byte[] and convert it to a file on the Sharepoint System. When I upload a file from the system I found no problem with file (till 50MB), when I load with my WS the call is leaved unless it is < 4MB.

I tried to modify the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200"/> //KB => 50MB
```

and then:

```
<security> 
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" > 
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" /> 
  </requestFiltering> 
</security>
```

do an IISReset but nothing has change: byte[] > 4MB is not accepted..

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but considering that you have no other answers here, SharePoint has its own file upload limits that need to be set in SharePoint's web.configs.  Hopefully that can get you started, sorry I can't be of more help.